# Looping through a 2d list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a 2d list that reads

```
items = [(1,20),(2,30),(3,40),(4,50),(5,60),(7,80),(8,90)]
```

What i want to do is create a loop that loops over the 2d list and takes each pair i.e 1,20 and writes them to a string

```
strText = "numberpair:" + str(items[i])
print (strText)
```

However i am not sure how i can read over these number pairs so they come out as a number pair in a loop and how to link the list to the str from the loop. Can someone show me how to write such a loop?

Comment: How do you want the output to look?

Answer (score 2):

From your example - the list contains tuples. In this case :

```
for pair in list:
   print(pair)
```

Will print each pair.

In case you need to access each item in the pair, you can use pair[0] and pair[1]

Comment: I believe `print pair` will also implicitly call `str()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner:

```
result = ''.join('numberpair: %s, %s\n'%(a,b)  for a, b in list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> items = [(1,20),(2,30),(3,40),(4,50),(5,60),(7,80),(8,90)]
>>> for x in items:
        print("numberpair: ", end='')  # suppress newline
        print(*x, sep=', ')            # separate with commas


numberpair: 1, 20
numberpair: 2, 30
numberpair: 3, 40
numberpair: 4, 50
numberpair: 5, 60
numberpair: 7, 80
numberpair: 8, 90
```